# Bad query to database with spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, database

I have some problem with my @query in API.
In my DB I have 1 table with 5 columns: id, imie, nazwisko, wiek, miasto.

I'm trying to make custom query to my DB and here we go -> errors.

When im making @Query like:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM osoba WHERE osoba.id = :id", nativeQuery = true)
```

**Result:**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "imie": "Szymon",
    "nazwisko": "Markowski",
    "wiek": 55,
    "miasto": "Sosnowiec"
}
```

And know im trying to make another query like:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT imie  FROM osoba WHERE osoba.id = :id", nativeQuery = true)
```

And here we go. It makes problem like:

```
2019-09-10 21:44:29.141 ERROR 8068 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column 'id' not found.
2019-09-10 21:44:29.158 ERROR 8068 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query; SQL [SELECT imie  FROM osoba WHERE osoba.id = ?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query] with root cause
```

Any ideas?

Comment: did you tried `osoba.imie`

Comment: add the `id` column to the select: `SELECT id, imie FROM osoba WHERE id = :id`

Comment: @thehandofNOD when I did what u said I'm getting error "Column 'miasto' not found." :D I dont know why im getting error with 'miasto' cause I dont use it here

Comment: @YCF_L errors from ur proposition :  Column 'id' not found.

Comment: @Szymon Did you put `@Param("id")` on your method's `id` parameter? By default, only position-based parameters (like `?1`) are supposed I think.

Comment: @AdamBukowiecki this is how it looks like                                                     @Query(value = "SELECT osoba.imie FROM osoba WHERE osoba.id = :id", nativeQuery = true)
Osoba findNameById(@Param("id") int id);

Comment: @Szymon How are you going to return `Osoba` object if you fetch `osoba.imie` only? ;) Shouldn't you return `String` instead?

Comment: I assume that you use Spring Data JPA. So the problem is that you don't select columns but an entity. In your case the entity is `Osoba` and Osoba contains this attribute. So you need to select it to be able to provide an instance of the entity `Osoba`

Comment: @AdamBukowiecki your solution works but... When im using object Osoba as return im getting the JSON object but if it is String only like this:                       [
    "Szymon,Markowski"
]

Comment: @thehandofNOD you are right. I have class with few attribute. Osoba as class is Entity. When I'm using Osoba class as return im getting message as JSON response. But when I'm using it as String return like:                                     String findNameById(@Param("id") int id); when im getting reponse only like a String not like a JSON. What should i do to change it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your repository does not know what kind of columns you returned and how to match them with your entity. First you need to change return type of your custom method, something like this:

```
@Repository
public interface OsobaRepository extend JpaRepository<Osoba, Integer> {
   @Query(value = "SELECT imie FROM osoba WHERE osoba.id = :id", 
          nativeQuery = true) 
   String findNameById(@Param("id") int id);
}
```

Now, if you want turn result from `String` to `Json`, in your `OsobaServiceImpl` (if its exists) your need to create an instance of the class `Osoba`, populate it and return to the controller, like this:

```
@Service
public ServiceOsobaImpl implementation ServiceOsoba {

    private final OsobaRepository osobaRepository;     

    @Autowired
    public ServiceOsobaImpl(OsobaRepository osobaRepository) {
        this.osobaRepository = osobaRepository;
    }

    // your methods
    ...

    public Osoba findNameById(int id) {
        String name = osobaRepository.findNameById(id);

        Osoba osoba = new Osoba();
        osoba.setName(name);

        return osoba;
    }

}
```

And another option, when your create simple `OsobaDto` with one field and use it (analogically previos option):

```
public OsobaDto implements Serializable {

    private String name;

    public OsobaDto() {}

    //getter and setter 
}


@Service
public ServiceOsobaImpl implementation ServiceOsoba {

    private final OsobaRepository osobaRepository;     

    @Autowired
    public ServiceOsobaImpl(OsobaRepository osobaRepository) {
        this.osobaRepository = osobaRepository;
    }

    // your methods
    ...

    public OsobaDto findNameById(int id) {
        String name = osobaRepository.findNameById(id);

        OsobaDto osobaDto = new OsobaDto();
        osobaDto.setName(name);

        return osobaDto;
    }

}
```

Both options response will be json-format. Naturally, if you specify `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` (or own analogically variant) above your controller method.

**UPDATE**.
If you use `Osoba` class and don't want to see `null` value, do the following.
Create new interface:

```
public interface OnlyName {}
```

The next step is to mark your entity as `@Validated` and annotate the field `imie` as `@JsonView`:

```
@Entity
@Validated
public class Osoba {

   // your code

   @JsonView(OnlyName.class)
   private String imie;

}
```

And the controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/osoba")
public class OsobaAPI {

    @Autowired
    private OsobaRepo osobaRepo;

    @JsonView(OnlyName.class)
    @PostMapping
    @RequestMapping("/getID")
    public Osoba findOsobaById(@RequestParam("id") int id){
        String name = osobaRepo.findNameById(id);
        Osoba osoba = new Osoba();
        osoba.setImie(name);
        return osoba;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did like u said I have something like that:

```
@Repository
public interface OsobaRepo extends CrudRepository<Osoba, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT imie FROM osoba WHERE osoba.id = :id", nativeQuery = true)
    String findNameById(@Param("id") int id);

}
```

---

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/osoba")
public class OsobaAPI {

    @Autowired
    private OsobaRepo osobaRepo;

    @PostMapping
    @RequestMapping("/getID")
    public Osoba findOsobaById(@RequestParam("id") int id){
        String name = osobaRepo.findNameById(id);
        Osoba osoba = new Osoba();
        osoba.setImie(name);
        return osoba;
    }
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class Osoba {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String imie;
    private String nazwisko;
    private int wiek;
    private String miasto;

    public Osoba() {
    }

    public Osoba(String imie, String nazwisko) {
        this.imie = imie;
        this.nazwisko = nazwisko;
    }

    public Osoba(int id, String imie, String nazwisko, int wiek, String miasto) {
        this.id = id;
        this.imie = imie;
        this.nazwisko = nazwisko;
        this.wiek = wiek;
        this.miasto = miasto;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getImie() {
        return imie;
    }

    public void setImie(String imie) {
        this.imie = imie;
    }

    public String getNazwisko() {
        return nazwisko;
    }

    public void setNazwisko(String nazwisko) {
        this.nazwisko = nazwisko;
    }

    public int getWiek() {
        return wiek;
    }

    public void setWiek(int wiek) {
        this.wiek = wiek;
    }

    public String getMiasto() {
        return miasto;
    }

    public void setMiasto(String miasto) {
        this.miasto = miasto;
    }
}
```

---

and the reasony from POSTMAN is:

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "imie": "Szymon",
    "nazwisko": null,
    "wiek": 0,
    "miasto": null
}
```

But wanted have reason from this query like

```
{
    "imie": "Szymon",
}
```

EDIT:

One more question about this topic.
That if I want to get response in JSON with for example: "imie, "nazwisko"?
I cannot use:

---

```
    @Query(value = "SELECT imie, nazwisko FROM osoba WHERE osoba.id = :id", nativeQuery = true)
    String findNameById(@Param("id") int id);

}
```

---

Cause response if as a String. And when im doing it I'm getting:

```
{
    "imie": null,
    "nazwisko": "IMIE, NAZWISKO"
}
```

Maybe should I use here String[] or create new Class with only these 2 atributes?

Comment: Yes, it's what I meant

Comment: If you do not want to see `null` value, use dedicate Data Transfer Object class (`OsobaDto` with one field in my example below) or configure your entity with annotation `@NotNull`, `@Null`, `@Valid`, `@JsonView` and etc.

Comment: Happy to help, choose my answer please